# Web service that converts HTTP GET to POST?

Tags: http, csrf, web-service

Is there some online forwarding service that I can give HTTP GET parameters to, and it would create a form with the parameters and submit it as POST?

For example, I'd like to give someone the URL:

```
http://imaginaryservice.com/http://reddit.com/post/login?username=guy&password=fawkes
```

...and when they click it, it should do the equivalent of submitting those parameters in POST to that URL (though the referer header would obviously reveal the trick).

Anyway, I know how I'd build one, but if something like that already exists, I'd like to know.

Comment: Hi @itsadok, welcome to [security.se]! Though I must say, that I don't see the security aspects of this question? If you do think it is a security question, please edit it to clarify the points you'd like to emphasize.

Comment: @AviD It seemed to me that it would be a simple tool to check a site for that particular XSRF vulnerability. I figured that the people here would know about such a service.

Comment: If you want to use this as a security tool, you should add that as context. That said, I'm not sure you're going about this the right way....

Comment: This strikes me as a blackhat kind of question.  I expect that these sites can be used to facilitate some kinds of attacks on websites, and to conceal your identity when attacking a website.  But what is the positive purpose for this?  If this is a blackhat question, it does not belong here.

Comment: @DW, it didnt sound blackhat to me, though it could of course be misused. Itsadok, it seems that you're looking for a way to test for CSRF, but going about this the wrong way around - could you add some context about what you're actually looking for? It could be you've already thought of a solution (service to translate GET to POST), when there could be a much better solution to your real problem.

Comment: **off-topic** because... Questions seeking product recommendations are off-topic as they become obsolete quickly. [Instead, describe your situation and the specific problem you're trying to solve.](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes there is.

http://tomengineering.tripod.com/gettopost.html

Comment: Hi @Schisis, thanks for this link! Can you please add a bit more info to the answer, explaining what the link is?

Answer (score 2):

There aren't any online services that I'm aware of that (intentionally) allow this type of behavior. If this is something you think you'll do on a regular basis, I highly recommend you look at [Web Scarab](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category%3aOWASP_WebScarab_Project) or [Pinata](http://code.google.com/p/pinata-csrf-tool/%20Pinata)